# Read and Write to the same text file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, filewriter

I have written this code to read from the file first after hashing the content from the file. It will write the original content plus hash values. But when I try to run the program the program will keep on writing and won't stop. what is the problem with my code?

```
package Encrypt;

import java.io.*; 
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Tan\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Tan\\Desktop\\Test.txt", true);
            
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String password = scan.nextLine();
            MessageDigest md;
            try {
                // Select the message digest for the hash computation -> SHA-256
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

                // Generate the random salt
                SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
                byte[] salt = new byte[16];
                random.nextBytes(salt);

                // Passing the salt to the digest for the computation
                //md.update(salt);

                // Generate the salted hash
                byte[] hashedPassword = md.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : hashedPassword)
                    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                //Print output
                System.out.println(password + " "  + sb.toString());
                //write output to text file
                writer.write(password + " "  + sb + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                writer.flush();
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        scan.close();
        writer.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Dont keep multiple streams to the same file open at the same time. They will interfere with each other and likely mess up everything, for example due to buffering and similar effects. Fully read the file, close the stream, do the edits and then fully write back. Also, use try-with-resources to ensure you do not get resource-leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You specified `true` as the [`append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean)) argument of `FileWriter`s constructor. So you are probalby reading what you previously written into the file.